# get query string in popup window

Tags: php, javascript

```
<a href="tags.php" onclick="return popitup('tags.php')">tags</a>
```

I have this line of code that runs the javascript to open new mini popup window,and it mostly works.

Now how could i add current query string attributes so that my popup window has url something like this "tags.php?variable1&variable2"

In few similar places I used this along with some other code to get the query attributes,the problem is that in this case page refreshes and contacts the sql without running javascript or opening window,when i try to make my code PHP using echo the quotation makrs f* everything up.

```
".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."
```

Comment: You can escape quotes with a backslash: `$txt = "this line has \"embedded\" quotes, but it's ok, because the backslash has my back"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return popitup('tags.php'+window.location.search)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return popitup(this.href + window.location.search);
```

would use the href belonging to the `<a>` that was clicked, so you don't have to retype it every time.